# If you cast Disguise Self and then Project Image, is the illusory copy from Project Image disguised?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, illusion, disguise

[*Disguise self*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/disguise-self)'s description contains the following:

> You make yourself--including your clothing, armor, weapons, and other belongings on your person--look different until the spell ends or until you use your action to dismiss it. You can seem 1 foot shorter or taller and can appear thin, fat, or in between. You can't change your body type, so you must adopt a form that has the same basic arrangement of limbs. Otherwise, the extent of the illusion is up to you.

[*Project image*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/project-image)'s description contains the following:

> You create an illusory copy of yourself that lasts for the duration. The copy can appear at any location within range that you have seen before, regardless of intervening obstacles. The illusion looks and sounds like you but is intangible. If the illusion takes any damage, it disappears, and the spell ends.
>
> You can use your action to move this illusion up to twice your speed, and make it gesture, speak, and behave in whatever way you choose. It mimics your mannerisms perfectly.

*Project image* doesn't say what happens if you cast it while already under a disguise. It says that it looks and sounds like you, but is that the real you or the illusion you?

**In other words, if I cast *disguise self* and then cast *project image*, does the illusory copy of me made by *project image* look like my actual appearance or the illusion from *disguise self*?**

RAW somewhere would be preferable, but I understand if no explicit rules exist.

Answer (score 15):

## Your disguised image will be projected.

The spell descriptions cited in the question have the relevant wordings (emphasis mine):

*Disguise self*:

> You make **yourself** ... look different.

*Project image*:

> You create an illusory copy of **yourself** that lasts for the duration.

In other words, *project image* is projecting the same thing that *disguise self* is disguising. The illusory copy is a copy of you, and you have modified your appearance, so that's how the copy appears.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your disguised self would appear, though I know of no explicit errata, this is just my logical deduction.

Disguise to me has always been equivalent to a change of clothes or putting on makeup, there’s a bit more to it in terms of altering behavior, but that’s the physical change; and Disguise Self the Spell just mimics those effects, though more easily and to a slightly greater extent. For all intents and purposes (except *True Sight*), it functions as a mundane disguise.

*Project Image* projects you as you are at that moment, with clothing and makeup; the projected image isn’t a picture of you naked unless you’re naked. If *Disguise Self* functions exactly like a mundane disguise, which for most purposes it does, then the same logic should follow. *Project Image* then would produce an image of your magically disguised self.